# Cannot add Integral Value to Timestamp without Frequency Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My Dataframe structures look like this:
Just a sample of one, have around 80.

[image]

```
start_dataset = pd.Timestamp(year=2011, month=6, day=1, freq=freq)
end_training = pd.Timestamp(year=2012, month=6, day=1, freq=freq)
```

Have my freq='M' in above code.

I'm trying to run this:

```
    training_data = [
    {
        "start": str(start_dataset),
        "target": ts[start_dataset:end_training - 1].tolist()  # We use -1, because pandas indexing includes the upper bound 
    }
    for ts in timeseries
]
print(len(training_data))
```

Following along to AWS's [DeepAR Notebook](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/deepar_electricity/DeepAR-Electricity.ipynb)

When executing this, I get the error of cannot add integral value to Timestamp without frequency. Searched for a bit but don't quite understand it. Any suggestions? Thought it might be a formatting issue with my date fields on my dataframes, but don't know why it would raise that error.

Comment: your issue is here `end_training - 1`, you're subtracting a `pd.Timestamp` type with `int`. The `1` here what does it mean? `1H`, `1D`.. or just the record before the last?

Comment: Yeah, it's an attempt to remove the last record in the end_training variable. start_dataset:end_training returns 13 records right now even though the Timestamps are a year apart.